# MediaWiki: Remove debug query strings (/load.php?debug=" )

Tags: performance, mediawiki, query-string

When I run a Google PageSpeed insights test I get problem reports for various long URLs with query strings for `/load.php?debug=`.

These problem reports appear for the loading of any webpage whatsoever.

How could I remove these query strings?

Comment: By not using the site in debug mode?

Comment: I didn't even know it is in it... Never had a case when a CMS starts in debug mode... I think this should be an answer like "Unlike may CMSs, MediaWiki starts at debug mode". I'll gladly accept (and thumb up for the sharpness).

Comment: Assuming that it is, because I never setted it on debug mode - not that I recall.

Comment: I went through `LocalSettings.php` and didn't find a debug variable, I also find nothing in special pages.

Comment: It's not in debug mode by default. It can be forced to be by setting `$wgResourceLoaderDebug` to true or adding `debug=1` to the URL.

Comment: I tried to add `$wgResourceLoaderDebug = false;` to the end of `LocalSettings.php`.; A Google Pagespeed Insights test still shows the same problem. Documentation seems partial (there is also completion template)...

Comment: When you browse your site, do you see the `debug` URL parameter in the URL?

Comment: @MrWhite when I browse it in general - no; I do not.